# Function calls function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        b
    def c(self):
        d(e)
    def d(self,g):
        print 1
```

I'm wondering what I should do if I want to use function d in function c as it turns that "global name d is not defined.". Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`d` is an instance method, so you call it using `self.d()`.

Answer (score 3):

You must call `self.d()` from your function.